# Why is my Android Database not storing anything?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-administration

I'm working on an Android app that also involves databases and I've run across a very annoying bug. I'm working on an example taken from the web.

The example below works just fine (no logcat errors). HOWEVER if I try and change the content of the KEY Strings, it stops working.

E.g. if I change
        KEY_LOCATION = "title" to KEY_LOCATION = "title1", the whole DB crashes.

I've also tried increasing the DB version number with no success so far. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="reminders";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=4;

public static final String KEY_LOCATION="title1";
public static final String KEY_BODY="body";
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME="date_time_value";
public static final String KEY_ROW_ID="_id";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( "+
                KEY_ROW_ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                KEY_LOCATION+ " text not null, "+
                KEY_BODY+" text not null, "+
                KEY_DATE_TIME+ " text not null);";

private Context mContext;

public DbAdapter(Context c){
    mContext=c;
}


public DbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException{
    mDbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    db=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public long createReminder(String title, String body, String dateTime){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, dateTime);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}
```

..................

These are the errors that I'm getting:

```
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:146)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at pirelli.app.dbadapter.PirelliDbAdapter.createReminder(PirelliDbAdapter.java:55)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at pirelli.app.dbadapter.PirelliDbAdapter.createReminder(PirelliDbAdapter.java:55)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at pirelli.app.HSEActivity$1.onClick(HSEActivity.java:149)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    11-29 21:43:02.722: E/SQLiteDatabase(2150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing.

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="reminders";
```

to

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="reminders2";
```

Comment: I did. And it crashes, that's what I'm saying :D

Comment: Have you tried changing the database name? instead the table?

Comment: Had to change both table AND database name. Thanks a lot for your help. It was an emulator problem. Thanks a million once again

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance there is already data in the database from an earlier test when you try to add this new data.

Since you added that data with a different key (title instead of title1) the database table is expecting you to insert data following the `title - body - date_time_value - _id` sequence.

You will need to drop your old database before inserting new data with different column names, or create a different table by changing your table name to something like `reminders2` as Coder said.

To drop your database, call this method:

```
public void dropTable() {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reminders");
    }
```

Comment: Mno...I hoped that it'd work but it's the same thing. Both changing the name as well as calling the dropTable function before doing anything else didn't work.

Comment: Hmm odd. I've had this error before but it was due to the fact that I forgot to empty my database after making some changes in my table columns. Could you post a more complete stack trace of the error? Usually the errors are a bit more extensive then just `Error inserting date_time_value=test2 body=test1 title1=test`

Comment: I think you're missing a part of the error actually. Normally the format is `Caused by: (error)   at  (location)` followed by the stack trace of calls before the error occured. Could you add the `Caused by` part?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks so much for helping me out. I had to change both Database name AND table name somehow... I suppose it'll work on an actual device. I'll get some code written and try it out soon. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. Glad to see you fixed your problem!